# Use class func on class parameter in Swift

Tags: swift, class

I am trying to use a class func to set a title for a book, however it's not working. Please see my code below:

```
import Foundation

class Book: NSObject {

    var bookTitle: String = ""
    var bookPage: String = ""

    override init(){
        print("Book object has been created")
    }



    class func setPageTitle(title: String)
    {
        bookTitle = title //I get the error here
    }

}
```

I want to make it mandatory to set a pageTitle when a Book object is created.

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: You're trying to set an instance variable when you have no instance.  Make `bookTitle` static.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Why is `setPageTitle` a class function?  Why not make `bookTitle` public?

Comment: If you want the title set on init, why provide a default value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to set any required property/attribute is when you initialize it. So try coding your class this way:

```
class Book: NSObject {

    var bookTitle: String = ""
    var bookPage: String = ""

    init(title:String) {
        bookTitle = title
        print("Book object has been created")
    }

}
```

Several notes:

1. Your error is because you declare `class` in your `setPageTitle` function. That makes no sense.
2. There are better (and other) ways to set the bookTitle, including *after* initialization. But you specifically wanted to make sure you have a title when initializing, so there you go.
3. There are definitely better ways to maintain the bookTitle attribute. (Most languages teach you to hold a price variable to start with.) I'm mostly trying to give you a way to initialize it with the class.
4. You probably don't need (or have) any superclass call to make, but you also may not need to make your Book class a NSObject either.

Comment: You probably should call `super.init()` if it is `NSObject` subclass. Or, as you say, don't make it `NSObject` subclass at all.

Comment: @Rob, I agree. My answer is specific to the question. If you subclass anything, you should call `super` unless there's a specific reason not to.